# How to configure LESS compiler in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition 14?

Tags: html, macos, intellij-idea, less, settings

I have installed Intellij IDEA ultmate IDE now I want to compile my LESS files and need to set LESS compiler.

```
Gone through these links - 1) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7059?pr=idea
2) https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/
3) https://www.jetbrains.com/editors/html_css_editor.jsp?ide=idea
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497601/configure-less-compiler-in-intellij-idea-ultimate-edition-14/32042755#32042755

Answer (score 1):

Settings | Tools | File Watchers, press + button, select "LESS" template.

Comment: OK, I have installed file watcher. After that I have selected tools->filewatcher pressed + "less" then 'ok'. Now when I am running .less file it is poping edit configuration.

Comment: Show the error message. I guess you dont have the npm package "Less" installed which is needed to compile your less files. Instructions can be found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html