# Configure LESS compiler in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition 14?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, less, settings

These are my settings. Here is the error i am facing while compiling .less file.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Install npm less module**

```
npm install -g less
```

**Step 2: Install the less plugins in Intellij Idea**

```
File > Settings > Plugins
```

[image]

**Step 3: Setup Less Profile**

```
File > Settings > LESS Profiles
```

[image]

It'll auto-generate the CSS file as soon as any change is noticed in LESS if "`Compile Automatically on Save`" is used.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly looking in `Project Strucutre`.

The Project `Settings` is the icon to the left (spanner).

Comment: Please add any snapshot. Still I didn't find any setting of LESS compiler in project panel(Left side).